# Detect iPad orientation when launch a app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, device-orientation

Is anyone know a way to detect the orientation of the iPad programmatically when launch a app.

I'm using following mechanism.

```
- (void) detectDeviceInitialOrientation
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate=(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

   if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
       appDelegate.orintation = PORTRAIT;
   }
   else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
       appDelegate.orintation = LANDSCAPE;
   }
}
```

But it fails to detect the device's orientation when it lay parallel to the floor. So, I'm looking another solution. Please help......

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [UIDeviceOrientation enum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDeviceOrientation) in the docs.

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

Notice that this defines `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` and `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`. Unfortunately, there is no built in check for whether the device is in one of these orientations like there is for portrait or landscape. However, you can do the checking your self with a simple if statement. Something like this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown) {
    // device is flat on the ground
}
```